# SOCIALENGINE - how to fetch Profile Info?

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

On the Members page, I am trying to modify the profile tags including only some info for each profile on Member.

How do I get each single value from that profile from the database? It should be something like this I believe but I am missing something and it doesnt work:

`<?php $viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
$fields = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias($viewer); ?>`

Thanks for your help

Comment: P.S. for some reason the site stripped off my code
<?php $viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
$fields = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias($viewer); ?>
<?php echo $fields['gender']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's values in a following way:

```
$aliasValues = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias($viewer);
$aliasValues['profile_type'];
```

You can see fields information in `engine4_user_fields_meta` database table (for example, you can find there `profile_type` alias). Please remember that not all fields have aliases, probably that's a reason why you're not getting much results.

Comment: Hi Kirk, thanks for your answer but unfortunately this solution breaks everything
I have tried with birthdate and something like this

<?php $viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
        $fields = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias($viewer); 
        $fields['birthday'];?>

and then <?php echo $fields; ?> between the div 

If I remove the $viewer it breaks the site, if I leave it doesnt do anything. 

Also, I have tried the echo option separated and everything in one instruction between div but nothing.

Comment: @Y.A. there is no need to remove `$viewer`, in my answer I assume that you already have it. I just wanted to take your attention to the database structure.

Comment: Hello Kirk, thanks but the second option is true than :(... and the script doesn't output anything for some reason. I'll try with different profile types but I feel there is something missing somewhere.